# Not displaying the total price in textbox

Tags: vb.net

```
Dim totalValue As Integer
For Each dgvRow As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView2.Rows
    If Not dgvRow.IsNewRow Then
        totalValue += CInt(dgvRow.Cells(3).Value)
    End If
Next
TextBox4.Text = totalValue
```

im having problem to this code it is not showing the total price of a column 3 or the Total column i put it in form load

[image: here's the example]

Comment: The problem is not in the code you posted. It's most likely a timing problem. When are the rows generated for the DataGridView?

Comment: right after clicking the add item

Comment: Then why don't you calculate the total after adding/removing an item, but on `Form_Load`...?

Comment: sorry to bother you. it works now i did not think in that way.